# Flatten all map columns recursively in PySpark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with multiple map columns. I want to flatten all map columns recursively. personal and financial are map type columns. Similarly, we might have more map columns.

**Input dataframe:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name |  Gender  |      personal                            |    financial                      |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  A   |    M     | {age:20,city:Dallas,State:Texas}         | {salary:10000,bonus:2000,tax:1500}|
| 2  |  B   |    F     | {city:Houston,State:Texas,Zipcode:77001} | {salary:12000,tax:1800}           |
| 3  |  C   |    M     | {age:22,city:San Jose,Zipcode:940088}    | {salary:2000,bonus:500}           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Output dataframe:**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  |   name   |   Gender  |  age   |  city    |   state   |   Zipcode   |   salary   |  bonus   |   tax   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   |   A      |   M       |   20   | Dallas   |  Texas    |     null    |    10000   |  2000    |   1500  |
| 2   |   B      |   F       |  null  | Houston  |  Texas    |     77001   |    12000   |  null    |   1800  |
| 3   |   C      |   M       |   22   | San Jose |  null     |    940088   |     2000   |  500     |   null  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What exactly do u mean by `recursively` here ?

Comment: means all map columns at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `map_concat` to merge the map fields and then explode them. exploding a map column creates 2 new columns - `key` and `value`. `pivot` the `key` column with `value` as values to get your desired output.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('personal_financial', func.map_concat('personal', 'financial')). \
    selectExpr(*[c for c in data_sdf.columns if c not in ['personal', 'financial']], 
               'explode(personal_financial)'
               ). \
    groupBy([c for c in data_sdf.columns if c not in ['personal', 'financial']]). \
    pivot('key'). \
    agg(func.first('value')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+----+------+-----+-------+----+-----+--------+------+----+
# |id |name|gender|State|Zipcode|age |bonus|city    |salary|tax |
# +---+----+------+-----+-------+----+-----+--------+------+----+
# |1  |A   |M     |Texas|null   |20  |2000 |Dallas  |10000 |1500|
# |2  |B   |F     |Texas|77001  |null|null |Houston |12000 |1800|
# |3  |C   |M     |null |940088 |22  |500  |San Jose|2000  |null|
# +---+----+------+-----+-------+----+-----+--------+------+----+
```